# Visual Studio Code doesn't show Intellisense with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

I'm new to software development, just started learning C# from online courses and I really want to get into game dev. So here's my situation:

I have a very low spec laptop and I don't want to use Visual Studio, so instead I use Visual Studio Code as my code editor. I have .NET Core installed (although my understanding of what .NET is, is actually very fuzzy) and I just got started with the [2D UFO Game Tutorial on the Unity website](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-ufo-tutorial).

Unity works fine, my scripts do as they're supposed to and I can follow the tutorials with (mostly) no issues. However, a big concern of mine is the fact that I almost NEVER get Intellisense or CodeLens, even when I have the correct `using` statements. This could be a problem when I need to find different methods, parameters, error messages etc. I never know when I have a method name wrong or if I don't have the correct `using` statements or if I'm using a reserved key word for Unity or C#.

One message I do get every time I open a script in VS Code from Unity is:

> Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more
>   details.

And when I do review the output console window, I get a very long set of messages that I don't understand, [you can find it here](https://pastebin.com/MK4kkKcu).

Comment: I will not recommend you to use Unity3D with a ***very low spec laptop***, you will get stuck quickly as you move into a bit more complex projects. Get yourself a decent second hand Desktop and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the document you posted on pastebin, the first thing that grabs my attention is **[fail]**. The very first time this occurs, on line 28 it states:

> OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo
>           .NET Framework v3.5 Service Pack 1 was not found. In order to target ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5", **.NET Framework v3.5 Service Pack 1 or later must be installed.**

Which suggests that you do not have .net framework 3.5 installed.

How to install this might differ somewhat per OS, but [unity3d forums, mono .net3.5 not installed](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/framework-mono-net-3-5-not-installed.448857/) would be a good starting point for the specifics on that.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that and wondered why it told me to install the .NET framework when i have .NET Core installed. It's a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @Ryan Unity makes use of the mono framework. This framework runs .net 3.5, and not .netcore. That's why you need the 3.5 installed

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following helps:

**Check if you can run "mono" on terminal.**

```
$ mono --version
```

**Check if you have mono installed at following location.**

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono
```

**if not, download and install mono from:**

https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

**now on terminal do:**

```
$ brew update
$ brew cask install mono
$ brew link --overwrite mono
```

mono should work and so does the Omni in visual studio/code.